# Disabling special treatment of an "unstable" application on Windows 7

Tags: windows, crash, sandbox

I do remember that Windows 7 have some technology that marks applications that crashed a few times and later executes them with more robust and slow system runtimes. It is possible to disable this feature or edit the list, but I cannot figure out how.

I would be grateful for any right keywords or links.

Note: It has nothing to do with DEP or UAC.

P.S. I tried to google it for more than an hour, but I can't find anything related.

Comment: The closes thing that springs to mind is the [Program Compatibility Assistant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756937.aspx) but it does not do exactly what you describe

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is not the thing.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of systems with both onboard and discrete video adapters?  AMD's software allows you to select which applications will use the less powerful onboard adapter and which will use the more powerful discrete adapter, and it may well automatically switch an application to the less powerful adapter if it crashes while using the more powerful one.

Comment: Sorry, no, it is not related to video at all. Seems like I am having a "false memory" - absolutely no info on the subject :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer myself - that is Fault Tolerant Heap :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx